# Visual Studio copies dll files which are set to "Do not copy"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

In my VS 2015 project I have a folder with some .dll files that I wanted to copy to the output directory using a post build script depending on the platform.

To prevent Visual Studio from touching them I set the property "Copy to output directory" to "Do not copy". I also set "Build Action" to "None".

But when I build the project some, but not all, of the .dll files are copied to the output directory anyway.
I have commented out my post build script.

The build output log says that the files are copied during a target "`_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal`":

```
1>Target "_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project
 "C:\SS\C#\InSQLMDASDriver2014R2\InSQLMDASDriverMain\InSQLMDASDriverMain.csproj" (target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" depends on it): 
1>Task "Copy"

... Copying of referenced assembly project output: 
1>  Copying file from "C:\SS\C#\InSQLMDASDriver2014R2\InSQLMDASDriverGui\bin\x86\Debug\InSQLMDASDriverGui.dll" to "bin\x86\Debug\InSQLMDASDriverGui.dll".

... Unwanted copying of static files below:

1>  Copying file from "C:\SS\C#\InSQLMDASDriver2014R2\InSQLMDASDriverMain\x64 Libraries\Historian.CBE.dll" to "bin\x86\Debug\Historian.CBE.dll". 
1>  Copying file from "C:\SS\C#\InSQLMDASDriver2014R2\InSQLMDASDriverMain\x64 Libraries\Historian.DPAPI.dll" to "bin\x86\Debug\Historian.DPAPI.dll".   

...    

1>Done executing task "Copy". 
1>Done building target "_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal" in project "InSQLMDASDriverMain.csproj".
```

Why is this happening..?

Comment: are those dlls referenced through `<Reference Include="..">` items in the csproj file?

Comment: dll's are referenced and marked as 'Copy Local' as would the name of the target suggests.

Comment: The dll's are not referenced, they are just inside a folder in the project.

Comment: @Ryebread, if you have set the property "Copy to output directory" to "Do not copy".and set "Build Action" to "None" with files inside a folder in the project, Visual Studio will not copy it to the output folder. You should double check it. If this issue is still persist, would you mind sharing us a sample to reproduce this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I've got a solution doing this as well happy to share the project it's on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

> In my VS 2015 project I have a folder with some .dll files that I wanted to copy to the output directory using a post build script depending on the platform.

Do you want to use a post build script to copy the dlls to output directory instead of using Visual Studio? If I understand you correctly, you should set the `copy local=False` for the dll in the property of References. For example:

[image]

With this setting, Visual Studio will not touch the dlls.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't always do what you tell it.